# Symbolic derivatives of special functions yield incorrect results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

When I evaluate with *Mathematica* this expression

```
D[ Abs[ Zeta[x + I y]], {x, 2}] + D[ Abs[ Zeta[x + I y]], {y, 2}]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

the result is zero which is an error.
Could you explain what's wrong?

Comment: This is abug in mathematica!

Comment: The result must be an Polynom with x and y.

Comment: D[Abs[[x + I y]], {x, 2}] + D[Abs[[x + I y]], {y, 2}]

Comment: this is also =0???

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* treats `Abs` as if it were (complex) differentiable, which, unfortunately, is not the case.  It returns `Abs'` when it is differentiated.  That indicates that *Mathematica* does not know what to do with the input.

One problem with the OP's problem is that the Chain Rule does not apply to expressions of the form `D[Abs[u[x,y]], x]`.  Another problem is that if one tries `D[ComplexExpand @ Abs[Zeta[x,y]], x]`, then we end up with the derivatives of `Re` and `Im`, which do not exist.

I do not know a way around this except by going back to the definition to compute the partial derivatives.  But even that has a problem.

```
Assuming[{Element[{x, y}, Reals]},
 d2 = Limit[(DifferenceDelta[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]], {x, 2, h}] + 
      DifferenceDelta[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]], {y, 2, h}])/h^2,
   h -> 0]
 ]
(*
  (Re[Zeta[x + I y]]^2 (-Derivative[1][Zeta][x + I y]^2 + 
        2 Re[Zeta[x + I y]] Derivative[2][Zeta][x + I y]) + 
     Im[Zeta[x + I y]]^2 (Derivative[1][Zeta][x + I y]^2 + 
        2 Re[Zeta[x + I y]] Derivative[2][Zeta][x + I y]))/(Im[
      Zeta[x + I y]]^2 + Re[Zeta[x + I y]]^2)^(3/2)
*)

d2 /. {x -> 2, y -> 1.}
(*
  -0.191142 + 0.0496602 I
*)
```

Hmm...why is there an imaginary part???  Let's check:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];

ND[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]] /. y -> 1, {x, 2}, 2] +
 ND[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]] /. x -> 2, {y, 2}, 1]
(*
  0.197487
*)

Limit[(DifferenceDelta[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]], {x, 2, h}] +
     DifferenceDelta[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]], {y, 2, h}])/h^2 /. {x -> 2., 
   y -> 1.},
 h -> 0]
(*
  0.197487
*)
```

Oh, well...it seems that the symbolic limit is wrong.  Perhaps someone will enlighten us.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround might be to express `Abs` in terms of `Conjugate`, so:

```
a = ComplexExpand[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]], TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]
```

> $\sqrt{\zeta (x-i y) \zeta (x+i y)}$

```
FullSimplify[D[a, {x, 2}] + D[a, {y, 2}]]
```

> $\frac{\zeta '(x-i y) \zeta '(x+i y)}{\sqrt{\zeta (x-i y) \zeta (x+i y)}}$

I don't know if this is the correct result, but it seems to agree with the results of `ND` (as shown in Michael's answer) for the few points I tested.

Comment: "I don't know if this is the correct result" - well, this at least is how I'd have done it.

Answer (score 2):

Please see answer by @michael-e2 as it is much better.  I'm using the chain rule, here, for arbitrary functions (which appears to be what Mathematica is doing), but this is not correct for |z| which is not complex differentiable.

Are you sure this is a bug?
Consider replacing `Abs` and `Zeta` with arbitrary functions `foo` and `bar`:

```
D[ foo[ bar[x + I y]], {x, 2}] + D[ foo[ bar[x + I y]], {y, 2}]
```

The first term and the last term differ only in sign.  By the chain rule all the factors in the derivatives are the same except for the `D[x + I y, x]` or `D[x + I y, y]` factors which are either `1` or `I`.  Taking the second derivative, this becomes a factor of `1` in the `x` derivative case and `-1` in the `y` derivative case.

Comment: f=x+iy ,|f|=x^2+y^2

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but Abs[z] for complex z is the modulus of z.  If z = x + i y, then Abs[z] will be computed as Sqrt[x^2 + y^2].

Comment: when you differentiate sqrt (x^2+y^2) there is no i

Comment: Yes, but that's not what you're differentiating.  You are differentiating Abs[Zeta[x + I y]].  If you want to know what the derivatives are with respect to x or y, you need to use the chain rule, and that will bring in factor i.

Comment: d^2/dx^2 |zeta(x)|+d^2/dy^2|zeta(x)| with your Argumentation this must be Zero wich is not

Comment: Of course it's not zero.  D[Abs[Zeta[x]],{x,2}] is not zero while D[Abs[Zeta[x]],{y,2}] is zero.  I think you meant to write D[Abs[Zeta[x]],{x,2}] + D[Abs[Zeta[y]],{y,2}] which isn't identically zero.  It also doesn't follow from my argument that it *should* be zero....

Comment: well the first Expression is not Zero thats my Point your comments Show how mathematica calculates them leading to a wrong result

Comment: Actually, I'm *totally wrong*, because |z| is not complex differentiable.  (Duh.)  So the chain rule doesn't apply.  See the post by @michael-e2

Comment: @ChristopherCole You do explain how *Mathematica* ends up with expressions that cancel each other, so perhaps not *totally* wrong. :)